# Using Parallel gem in Ruby; how many cores to use?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a section of slow code that I want to speed up by using the `parallel` gem and multiple cores.

With the Parallel gem, you must specify the number of processes or threads you want to use, so I hard-coded it to use the same number of logical cores that I have. It works perfectly, but my problem is that this code is intended to be distributed and used by other people who may have a different number of cores.

Should I try to detect the number of cores that their machine has, and use that number? Or should I default to no parallelism and only switch to multi-threaded code if the user explicitly specifies the number of threads they'd like to use? (e.g. `pg_restore`)

If I do try to detect cores, should I try to utilise all cores found, or would it be more polite to use, say, all but one of the cores?

Comment: What's your use case? Am I giving you a massive file to process or are you running a daemon? In other words, I wouldn't let you water my lawn with a firehose, but I'd sure as hell let you use one to save my house from burning to the ground.

Comment: In this case, I'm populating a database with test data; so not super critical. It's a CLI tool for performing a one-off task that the user might perform only once or twice. But it's the difference between 12 minutes and 1 minute (on my computer). It's an issue I've encountered before though, and I wondered if there's a generally accepted practice.

Comment: The question is rather broad and answer would be case specific. Performance gain vs memory usage, target platform (support of COW optimizations), used Ruby implementation etc.

Comment: You can provide a config file and let the users decide how many processes/threads should be spawned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea how memory-intensive your program is but those requirements could also cause major unexpected issues for people with less memory than the machine you're testing it on.

Since it's a CLI tool, why not add a flag like `--procs` that takes an argument for the number of processes to use, and leave it up to the user to decide?

Comment: In this instance, it actually uses very little memory, it just hammers the CPU.  I hadn't thought of memory though; that's an important consideration.